# Mapping of strings in database

Tags: android, database, string, mapping

i am writing an android program in which i have a text generated. ,with a database of words and the word related text content.when the text generated matches with the word it need to display the text content instantaneously.Example -database has text content for facebook,orkut,linkedin. and  .when the text content generated is facebook , it matches with the facebook word of database and displays facebook details.
how can i perform this in android.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: how do i map the generated text with the database word.  generation of  the text and creation of  a database can be done

Comment: @ seshu ,sorry seshu- its a lengthy code to show. what we gets is a string generated by ocr and i want to display the message for the generated ocr string which is predefined in a database.